# Find relationships between two columns in two csv files

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to do this in R. I have two periodical time series datasets stored in two different cvs files. The dataset timestamp did not match. Any solution to find their relationships in general?

My intention is to find if variable (i.e., price) in timeseries1.csv are affected by variable transportation in timeseries2.csv during the matched time frame.

Two csv files are here:

[timeseries1.csv](https://db.tt/QX3ahHtn)

[timeseries2.csv](https://db.tt/rKdmpo8r)

Any useful R packages for this task? Please provide a quick example code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This does not appear to be a specific programming question. Request for package or off-site tutorials are off-topic for this site. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical analysis for your data, you might want to try asking over at [stats.se]. But be clear what hypothesis you want to test exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [itsmr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsmr/itsmr.pdf) package in R. It has a bunch of functions you can use to check autocorrelations and other time series analysis stuff. It is based on an older time series software called ITSM.